# Use utility class in web application or web service?

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, servlets

I know how to make web application in technologies like jsp/servlets and applications servers.

Suppose I make some utility method for particular application say ‘A’ and its working fine no any other web or desktop application in need of this method.

Same thing I can provide such utility method via web service like Rest/Soap.

So why I need web service in this scenario, I can imagine if such service is useful for other application and we provide it as web service then its fine.

Can anyone give me some answer which clear my doubt?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is a bit weird Please explain properly the line: 

"So why I need web service in this scenario, I can imagine if such service is useful for other application and we provide it as web service then its fine."

Comment: I mean that service is only useful for one web application only.

Comment: If the service is usefull for any client (one or more) then expose the utility through web service. else don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Your Comment, i would like to clarify.

Web service is a concept in which you expose a utility or functionality to the world.

Any one in the world can access the same by first establishing ground rules as in SOAP via WSDL.

The Services can serve any number of requests from any application provided it sends the proper input request needed by your service.

In case you have built an application A with a utility functionality X,

Then application B,C,D and so on can access the Web Service.

All it needs is:

- the URL for the Service which is exposed through network to the consuming application
- The requested parameter format
- and the Proper Response format.

Once this is setup, any application, not just in java, can access the service so even .Net applications or PL/SQL applications can access the Web Service Utility.